# Limit of rational function of 2 variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

How can you show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{2x^2y(x^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2} = \nexists$$

The non-existence of the limit has been verified using a limits calculator.
I tried to apply restrictions like $y=x^\alpha$ and $y=mx$ but along these directions the function tends to $0$.
I also tried to estimate the function from below with $$\frac{x(x^2+y^2)(y^4-x^2)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}$$ knowing that $-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)\leq(xy)$ but I couldn't go any further.
In the end I tried to sobstitute with polar coordinates but I obtained the same result: function tends to $0$

Thanks to anyone who wants to help me.

Comment: I've tried another solutions using inequalities. Maybe there is some other more effective way. Let see what can be done from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2$ and $y^4$  are nonnegative...

$$  x^4 \leq (x^2 + y^4)^2 $$
$$ \frac{x^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}  \leq 1 $$

$$ 0 \leq (x^2 - y^4)^2 , $$
$$ 4 x^2 y^4 \leq (x^2 + y^4)^2 , $$
$$ \frac{x^2 y^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}  \leq \frac{ 1}{4} $$
$$ \frac{ x^4 -x^2 y^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^2}  $$

$ |A-B| \leq |A| + |B|$
$$ \left| \frac{ x^4 -x^2 y^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^2} \right|  \leq 1 + \frac{1}{4}  = \frac{5}{4}  $$

$$ \color{red}{ \left| \frac{ 2y ( x^4 -x^2 y^4)}{(x^2 + y^4)^2} \right|  \leq    \frac{5|y|}{2} } $$

Comment: Nice derivation! We agree with the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y^4=v^2$ then

$$\left|\frac{2x^2y(x^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}\right|=\frac{2x^2\sqrt{|v|}|x^2-v^2|}{(x^2+v^2)^2}$$

and by polar coordinates

$$2\rho^{\frac12}\cos^2\theta\sqrt{|\sin \theta|}|\cos^2\theta-\sin^2 \theta| \to 0$$

---

**Edit**

As an alternative we have that

- for $x^2=y^4$

$$\frac{2x^2y(x^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2} =0$$

- for $x^2>y^4$

$$\left|\frac{2x^2y(x^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}\right| =\frac{2x^2|y|(x^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}\le \frac{2x^4|y|-2x^2|y|^5}{4x^4}=\frac{|y|}{2}-\frac{|y|^5}{2x^2} \to 0$$

indeed

$$\frac{|y|^5}{2x^2}\le \frac{|y|^5}{2y^4}=\frac{|y|}{2}\to 0$$

- for $y^4>x^2$

$$\left|\frac{2x^2y(x^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}\right| =\frac{2x^2|y|(y^4-x^2)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}\le \frac{2x^2|y|^5-2x^4|y|}{4y^8}=\frac{x^2}{2|y|^3}-\frac{x^4}{2|y|^7} \to 0$$

indeed

$$\frac{x^2}{2|y|^3} \le \frac{y^4}{2|y|^3} =\frac{|y|}2 \to 0$$

$$\frac{x^4}{2|y|^7} \le \frac{y^8}{2|y|^7}=\frac{|y|}2 \to 0$$

Comment: Both dimostrations with polar coordinates and with inequalities seems right and general to me, maybe it's just a bug of Wolframalpha...

Comment: Anyway, thanks again

Comment: @daniele Also the other answer agrees with the result! Bye